# NGINX FastCGI "Primary script unknown" on every other image upload POST

Tags: nginx, php, docker, php-fpm, fastcgi

I have a simple upload php script that accepts image jpg files and saves them to a screenshots directory then returns the link to the client. In pre-deployment testing, I am running into the nginx service erroring out every other request as shown in my screenshot. My environment is running in Docker containers and I have checked the config and file permissions and all is in order.

[image: FastCGI error every other request]

Here is my Nginx.conf file to show the FastCGI configuration...

```
user nginx;
worker_processes 8;

error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
    multi_accept on;
    use epoll;
}

http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    log_format main '$proxy_protocol_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] [$host] "$request" $status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;

    charset utf-8;
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 15;

    port_in_redirect off;
    server_name_in_redirect off;

    index index.php index.html;
    autoindex off;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css text/xml application/xml application/javascript application/atom+xml application/rss+xml application/json;

    client_body_buffer_size 200m;
    client_max_body_size 25m;

    server_tokens off;

    map $http_x_forwarded_proto $fe_https {
        default off;
        https on;
    }

    server {
        listen 0.0.0.0:80;
        server_name _;
        root /www/;

        location / {
            location ~* \.php$ {
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /www/$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_pass php:9000;
                try_files $uri =404;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The upload.php script that handles image uploads to the server:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/text");

$secret_key = "";
$domain_url = "http://images.sonoranrp.com/";
$sharexdir = "screenshots/";
$safe_types = ["jpg", "jpeg"];

#Comment this next line if you want Robots to index this site.
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == "/robot.txt") { die("User-agent: *\nDisallow: /"); }

#Don't edit past this point!
if(isset($_FILES['files']))
{
    $target_file = $_FILES["files"]["name"][0];
    $fileType = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $filename = GetFilename($fileType);
    //not sure how save that is, but you can use this instead:
    //$fileType = strtolower(end(explode(".", $target_file)));
    if (in_array($fileType, $safe_types))
    {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][0], $sharexdir.$filename.'.'.$fileType))
        {

            echo "{\"url\": \"$domain_url$sharexdir$filename.$fileType\"}";
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'File upload failed - CHMOD/Folder doesn\'t exist? ';
        }
    }
}
else
{
    echo 'No post data recieved';
}

function GetFilename($fileType) {
    srand(time());
    $filename = null;
    while (true) {
        $filename = uniqid(rand(), true);
        if (!file_exists("screenshots/".$filename)) break;
    }
    return $filename;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I am dumb...

Found out that on my docker-compose/docker network I was duplicating container names on that specific internal network. This caused the docker DNS service to have the two containers fighting for the dns name of php.network_default and nginx.network_default...

Seems that was the main issue behind the weird behavior...